# min-width not working with CSS grid in Chrome or Edge

Tags: css, css-grid

I want the iframe in my page to be horizontally centered. I think my code is correct, and in fact the page looks fine in Firefox, but when I open it in Chrome or Edge, the iframe does not shrink properly to fit the grid cell.

If you run this code on Chrome you will see this (undesired):

[image]

which is not correct since the iframe is taking that extra yellow space on the right, forcing the horizontal scrollbar to appear.

If you open this on Firefox, on the other hand, you will see that the behavior is different (desired):

[image]

```css
@media only screen and (min-device-width :1300px) and (max-device-width: 1600px) {
  html,
  body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: white;
  }
  .container {
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 8fr 2fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  }
  .center-container {
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 12fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 3fr 1fr 2fr 1fr 12fr;
  }
  .right-container {
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
  .sponsor-item-container-1 {
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 3fr 12fr 1fr;
    height: 33vh;
  }
  .sponsor-logo-item-1 {
    grid-column: 2 / 5;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
  }
  .iframe-sponsor-1 {
    grid-column: 2 / 10;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
  }
  .website-container-1 {
    grid-column: 2 / 10;
    grid-row: 3 / 4;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    justify-items: center;
  }
  .sponsor-item-container-2 {
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 3fr 12fr 1fr;
    height: 33vh;
  }
  .sponsor-logo-item-2 {
    grid-column: 2 / 5;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
  }
  .iframe-sponsor-2 {
    grid-column: 2 / 10;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
  }
  .website-container-2 {
    grid-column: 2 / 10;
    grid-row: 3 / 4;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    justify-items: center;
  }
  .sponsor-item-container-3 {
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    grid-row: 3 / 4;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 3fr 12fr 1fr;
    height: 33vh;
  }
  .sponsor-logo-item-3 {
    grid-column: 2 / 5;
    grid-row: 1 / 2;
  }
  .iframe-sponsor-3 {
    grid-column: 2 / 10;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
  }
  .website-container-3 {
    grid-column: 2 / 10;
    grid-row: 3 / 4;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    justify-items: center;
  }
  .right-container {
    background-color: white;
    -moz-box-shadow: -5px 0 5px -5px #333333;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -5px 0 5px -5px #333333;
    box-shadow: -25px 0 25px -25px #333333;
  }
  .iframe-sponsor-1 {
    min-width: 0px;
    min-height: 0px;
  }
  .iframe-sponsor-2 {
    min-width: 0px;
    min-height: 0px;
  }
  .iframe-sponsor-3 {
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 0px;
  }
  .sponsor-logo-item-1 {
    background: url('https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/oracle-1.svg');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
  .sponsor-logo-item-2 {
    background: url('https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/oracle-1.svg');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
  .sponsor-logo-item-3 {
    background: url('https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/oracle-1.svg');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="center-container">
  </div>
  <div class="right-container">
    <div class="sponsor-item-container-1">
      <div class="sponsor-logo-item-1"></div>
      <iframe class="iframe-sponsor-1" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VAgRVO15GTc"></iframe>
      <div class="website-container-1">
        <a href="https://www.oracle.com/index.html" target="_blank">Oracle website</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sponsor-item-container-2">
      <div class="sponsor-logo-item-2"></div>
      <iframe class="iframe-sponsor-2" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VAgRVO15GTc"></iframe>
      <div class="website-container-2">
        <a href="https://www.oracle.com/index.html" target="_blank">Oracle website</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sponsor-item-container-3">
      <div class="sponsor-logo-item-3"></div>
      <iframe class="iframe-sponsor-3" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VAgRVO15GTc"></iframe>
      <div class="website-container-3">
        <a href="https://www.oracle.com/index.html" target="_blank">Oracle website</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem you're describing is not being reproduced with the code provided.

Comment: Look at the top image: that is what i see if i run the code on chrome. As you can see, the iframe is not horizontally centered (i have highlighted a yellow band to show that). You don't see that? What version of chrome are you running? I am running Version 85.0.4183.102 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using `min-device-width` and `max-device-width`. These 2 query tresholds are hardware dependant. Best practice for responsive websites  is to use `min-width` and `max-width`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
iframe {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Edit: You code shouldn't be working at all, but works in Firefox due to a bug. In Firefox v81, `min-width:0;` and `min-height:0;` will cease to work on iframes the way you're using it, and your code will break if you don't change it. You should change it to `max-width:100%;` instead.

See: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1664647

Comment: This does solve my problem. But can you speak a little bit more to it? And, why was it working in Firefox?

Comment: @BabaNew https://codepen.io/Terrafire123/pen/KKzRrmy It appears that Firefox treats min-width and min-height on iframes differently that Chrome does. Browsers tend to have different default settings, which are usually mitigated by CSS resets... though I doubt a CSS reset would have helped here.

Comment: @BabaNew If it makes you feel better, it'll be fixed in Firefox version 81. (Rather, Firefox will start working like Chrome, and your old code will break, once Firefox v81 is released.) https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1664647

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script type="application/javascript">

function resizeIFrameToFitContent( iFrame ) {

    iFrame.width  = iFrame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth;
    iFrame.height = iFrame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {

    var iFrame = document.getElementById( 'iFrame1' );
    resizeIFrameToFitContent( iFrame );

    // or, to resize all iframes:
    var iframes = document.querySelectorAll("iframe");
    for( var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
        resizeIFrameToFitContent( iframes[i] );
    }
} );

</script>

<iframe src="usagelogs/default.aspx" id="iFrame1"></iframe>
```